# What would you do if the author of a published CS article does not respond to code requests?

Tags: programming-languages, simulation, research, experimental-analysis

Since reproducibility is a major principle or basic norm of scientific experiments, simulations, and computations, what would you do or what to do if the author of a published CS article does not respond to code requests?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's too little information to provide an answer here, perhaps the author is busy?  In theoretical computer science, there's not a lot of focus on "scientific experiments, simulations and computations"; rather mathematical proofs are the foundation.  There are many CS articles where the authors never actually implemented the algorithm, but did the mathematical analysis.

Comment: Perhaps this is more appropriate for [academia.se].

Comment: Let’s say the author left academia, has a well paid job requiring lots of overtime, and no time, no motivation, no obligation, and no intent to help you instead of spending a bit of time with their husband or kids - there’s nothing you can do other than offering a generous amount of money that makes it worth their while.

Comment: Cross-posted.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.